# webflux multipartData with file and string

Tags: spring-webflux, multipartform-data, flux

receive code

```kotlin
        fun uploadImage(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {


            return req.body(BodyExtractors.toMultipartData())
                .map {
                    Pair(
                        it.toSingleValueMap().getOrDefault("image", null),
                        it.toSingleValueMap().getOrDefault("fileName", null)
                    )
                }
                .filter { Objects.nonNull(it.first) && Objects.nonNull(it.second) }
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
                .flatMap { pair ->


                    DataBufferUtils.join(pair.first.content())
                        .map { dataBuffer ->
                            gcsRepository.saveFile(
                                dataBuffer,
                                UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "fileName"
                            )
                        }
                        .map { blob -> blob.asBlobInfo().mediaLink }
                }.flatMap { ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(UploadImageFileResponse(it)) }
                .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
```

send code

```
curl --location 'http://local-av-api.digo.im/challenge-api/v1/images' \
--form 'image=@"/C:/Users/home/Downloads/logo.png"' \
--form 'fileName="hello.png"'
```

When I call gcsRepository.saveFile method, I want to use fileName data in request.
How to use fileName in another flux? Help me. It is too difficult flux, mono stream...Thanks

When I call gcsRepository.saveFile method, I want to use fileName data in request.